# What is the best practice for getting compiled files onto production servers

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm not sure if this question has already been asked in the passed or not, I've been strolling through blogs and tutorials and not yet come across exactly what I'm looking for, looking for some advice on where to get started.

So my situation. I have a React App that gets build via webpack. I have had a read into getting the production code onto servers and that you should not build them directly on the prod servers, but instead push the compiled files at this stage.

What would be the best practice for getting these files committed?

- If I remove the compiled files from the `.gitignore` and add them, pull on production and then add them back to the `.gitignore` once this process has been complete then would this not create conflicts on the complied files for the Dev's on their next pull?
- Or do we set up a whole separate branch for production and commit the
  build files to this branch following the same process as above?

Is there any hard and fast rules around this? Or has anyone come up with some kind of process to use as a guideline?

Comment: You need a build server which pulls changes from Git, compiles them and packages the results. No need to add these packages back into Git, they should be reproducible (at least functionally) by checking out the same commit and building it again.

Comment: So the build server compiles the files, how do the new compiled files get onto the prod server from here? Or is the build server the prod server in this instance?

Comment: The build server packages the build results and publishes those in one way or another to the application servers.